# How to mock a function in jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to make a test mocking a function in my react component, for example I have:

```
const app=()=>{

const [state,setState]=useState("");

const func=(item)=>{
   setState(item)
}

  return(
   <div>{state}<div/>
  )
}
```

and I want to test that function called "func" with jest and enzyme
for this example I have :

```
let wrapper=mount(<App/>)

test("testing",()=>{
   let item="test"
   //mock function -> func(item)
  // how to mock that function 
  }
)
```

can someone help me with the syntax?

Comment: How is `func` triggered?

Comment: @wentjun I want to test a function that is not triggered by click, for this example lets say its useEffect or a side effect of another function.

Comment: I see.. Hmm.. Did you manage to figure it out? I posted my answer below. Can't really help much except for what I have written unless you post more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can spy on and mock results from method properties in class based components, you can't use the same approach for functional components.

What you should do is to trigger or simulate the particular behaviour that calls the `func` method in your functional components, and then test the expected behaviour (i.e if the props method is called, or changes in DOM elements, etc).

If it is triggered by the `useEffect()` hook, you will have to trigger that hook by updating the props (using [setProps](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.html)) that is used in the dependency array.